# Creating a subprocess in Django view and return the result to the client

Tags: python, django, subprocess, django-rest-framework

In my Django application I have to run a subprocess that will do some work and return the result to the client. I'm doing like this :

```
def get(self, request, id=None ):
    pid = os.fork()
    if not pid :
        # child process
        result = do_some_work()
        return Response(result)
    else :
        # I don't know what to put here
        # I tried this
        time.sleep(60)
```

The work I do in the subprocess doesn't take a long time. My code doesn't work, I have tried to add nothing in parent process code but that doesn't work because the function doesn't return anything. So I though I will wait until the child process return the result. It doesn't work too and I get `IOError: failed to write data`.

How can I fix this? Or what is the better solution to my problem?

Comment: haave u seen this http://www.python-course.eu/forking.php

Comment: Why do you think that it will help me? It just explain how `fork` work and it's not what I need here.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Why would you want to fork in the first place if the work you are doing doesn't take long?

Comment: @ThomasFenzl I must execute the code in a subprocess, it's a constraint of the software I use to do the work. My problem is that my view doesn't return the result.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is to offload processing and make it async. You shouldn't do that the way you've done in Django.

Here is a good comparision of libraries that can help you: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/workers-queues-tasks/

Comment: Explain your answer more please. I don't see how to do what you're suggesting.

Comment: There is plenty of documentation on each of those libraries to explain how to do what you are trying to do. This site is not for asking other people to write code for you.

Comment: I'm not asking you to write code for me. If you answer a question answer it the better way otherwise just write a comment or better don't answer it. I don't see any relation between what I'm asking and what you suggesting.